# Unable to cover Test class on Approval process. 69% covered only

Tags: apex, unit-test, approval-process

```
public with sharing class T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass {
public string comments{get;set;}
public Opportunity oppty {get;set;}
private string id;
private List<Id> prosInsIds = new List<Id>();    
public List<ProcessInstance> prosIns{get;set;}
private List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem>  prosInsWrkItms = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem>(); 
public List<ProcessInstance > proInstsLst{get; set;}   

public T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    oppty=[select id,Name,StageName,T_Status__c from Opportunity where id=:id];
    prosIns = new List<ProcessInstance>();
    prosIns = [SELECT Id, Status, TargetObject.Id, TargetObject.Name, TargetObject.Type, CreatedDate FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObject.Type='Opportunity' and TargetObject.Id=:id];
    for(ProcessInstance prIns: prosIns){
        prosInsIds.add(prIns.Id);
    }
    prosInsWrkItms =  [SELECT Id, ProcessInstance.Id, ProcessInstance.Status, Actor.Id, Actor.Name, Actor.Type FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.Id in : prosInsIds];


   }

   public void appRej(String appRej){

        for(ProcessInstance pi : getProsInsts()){

            for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem  pwi  : prosInsWrkItms){

                if(pi.Id == pwi.ProcessInstance.Id){

                    Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
                    string usercommand='"Approve (Under Condition)" '+ Comments;
                    req.setComments(usercommand);
                    req.setAction(appRej);
                    if(appRej == 'Approve')
                    req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {pwi.Actor.id});        
                    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> procWrkItms = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem>();
                    procWrkItms  = [Select Id from ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.Id =: pi.Id];                    

                if((!(procWrkItms.isEmpty()) && procWrkItms[0].Id!=null)){
                    req.setWorkitemId(procWrkItms[0].Id);        
                   //Submit the request for approval    
                    Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    public List<ProcessInstance> getProsInsts() {

        if(proInstsLst== null) {
            proInstsLst = new List<ProcessInstance>();
            for(ProcessInstance p : [SELECT Id, TargetObject.Id, status, TargetObject.Name, TargetObject.Type, CreatedDate FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObject.Id=:id]) {
               proInstsLst.add(p);
            }
        }
        return proInstsLst;
    }


        public pagereference approveAll(){
        appRej('Approve');
        Pagereference pg = new PageReference('/' + id);
        pg.setredirect(true);
        return pg;

    }
    public pagereference rejectAll(){
        appRej('Reject');
        Pagereference pg = new PageReference('/' + id);
        pg.setredirect(true);
        return pg;
        }

    public pagereference ApproveUnderCon(){
        appRej('Approve');
        Pagereference pg = new PageReference('/' + id);
        pg.setredirect(true);
        Opportunity  opptyupdatestatus=[select id,T_Status__c from Opportunity where id=:id];
        if(opptyupdatestatus.T_Status__c=='Approved - DC-VF Controller'){
        system.debug('IfPart------->'+opptyupdatestatus.T_Status__c);
        opptyupdatestatus.T_Status__c='Approved Under Conditions - DC-VF Controller';
        }
        else{
        system.debug('elsepart------->'+opptyupdatestatus.T_Status__c);
        opptyupdatestatus.T_Status__c='Approved Under Conditions - DC-VF Controlling Director';
        }
        update opptyupdatestatus; 

        return pg;

    }
}

> Below is test class for the above, which shows error "NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found"
```

> Below is the test class which covers 69% only.

---

```
@isTest
public class T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass_Test {
    static testMethod void approvetest(){
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('T-OPP-DCVF-RT').getRecordTypeId();
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Name = 'ramesh';
            acc.montant__c=0.2;
            insert acc;

            opportunity opp=New opportunity();
            opp.Name = 'Test678';
            opp.StageName = 'Proposal to Customer';
            opp.RecordTypeId=devRecordTypeId ;
            opp.T_Status__c='Not Started';
            opp.CloseDate = system.today();
            insert opp;
            opp.StageName = 'Draft';
            update opp;

            Profile p = [select id from Profile where profile.name='T_DCVF User' limit 1];

            User u = new User(ProfileId = p.id,LastName = 'Test', FirstName = 'Test', Username ='test7778@gmail.com', Alias='test',Email='test7778@gmail.com', TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US');
            Insert u;
            System.runAs(u) {
            // The following code runs as user 'u' 
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
            }

            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
            T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass rp = new T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass(sc);
            rp.appRej('Approve');
            rp.approveAll();
            rp.ApproveUnderCon();
            rp.getProsInsts();
            rp.rejectAll();


            List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = [select Id, Status from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId = :opp.id];
            System.assertEquals(processInstances.size(),0);


    }
}
```

[image: ## Heading ##]

> Below is the test class that I modified, but got error as :System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

```
    @isTest
private class T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass_Test {
    static testMethod void approvetest(){
       devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('T-OPP-DCVF-RT').getRecordTypeId();

            Profile p = [select id from Profile where profile.name='T DCVF User' limit 1];

            User u = new User(ProfileId = p.id,LastName = 'Test', FirstName = 'Test', Username ='test7778@gmail.com', Alias='test',Email='test7778@gmail.com', TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US');
            Insert u;
            System.runAs(u) {

            // The following code runs as user 'u' 
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
            opportunity opp=New opportunity();
            opp.Name = 'Test678';
            opp.StageName = 'Draft';
            opp.RecordTypeId=devRecordTypeId ;
            opp.T_Status__c='Not Started';
            opp.CloseDate = system.today();

            insert opp;

            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
            req.setObjectId(opp.Id);

            Approval.ProcessResult resu = Approval.process(req);

            // Verify the result
            System.assert(resu.isSuccess());

            System.assertEquals('Pending', resu.getInstanceStatus(),'Instance Status'+resu.getInstanceStatus());
            system.debug('status for approval::'+resu.getInstanceStatus());
            List<Id> newWorkItemIds = resu.getNewWorkitemIds();
            system.debug('newWorkItemIds ::'+newWorkItemIds );

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 =  new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
            req2.setComments('Approving request.');
            req2.setAction('Approve');
            req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});//UserInfo.getUserId()
            system.debug('req2::'+req2);
            // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
            req2.setWorkitemId(newWorkItemIds.get(0));
            system.debug('req3::'+req2);
            // Submit the request for approval
            Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req2);

            // Verify the results
            System.assert(result2.isSuccess(), 'Result Status:'+result2.isSuccess());

            System.assertEquals(  'Approved', result2.getInstanceStatus(),'Instance Status'+result2.getInstanceStatus());

            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
            T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass rp = new T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass(sc);
            rp.appRej('Approve');
            rp.approveAll();
            rp.ApproveUnderCon();
            rp.getProsInsts();
            rp.rejectAll(); 

       } 

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of calling approval process in your test class just call the main class method.

Comment: I tried to call the main class methods, but its not covering.

Comment: @Tushar, could you please suggest, now its 69 % covered. but still unable to hit the approval process.

Comment: check the process instance record . Once you get them in test class code coverage will increase. `where Status='Pending' and TargetObject.Id=:id` try to match this condition.

Comment: Hi Have tried with this way also, but no luck.

Comment: Could any one please help to increase to code coverage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks very similar to a previous question: [ProcessInstanceWorkitems not created when running an Approval Process unit test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17981/processinstanceworkitems-not-created-when-running-an-approval-process-unit-test)

Basically, you need to retrieve the ProcessWorkItems once you initiate the Approval.  Currently the list of ProcessWorkItems is empty, so there's nothing to iterate over (At the start of your Red coverage).  The answer to the linked question (which I claim no credit for) provides an approach to test the Approval Process AND its process work items.

======
Alex:  Adding in further code and error supplied by Mitesh:

Below is the test class that I modified but got error as:

> System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] at line 52.

```
@isTest
private class T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass_Test {
    static testMethod void approvetest(){
       devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('T-OPP-DCVF-RT').getRecordTypeId();

            Profile p = [select id from Profile where profile.name='T DCVF User' limit 1];

            User u = new User(ProfileId = p.id,LastName = 'Test', FirstName = 'Test', Username ='test7778@gmail.com', Alias='test',Email='test7778@gmail.com', TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US');
            Insert u;
            System.runAs(u) {

            // The following code runs as user 'u' 
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
            opportunity opp=New opportunity();
            opp.Name = 'Test678';
            opp.StageName = 'Draft';
            opp.RecordTypeId=devRecordTypeId ;
            opp.T_Status__c='Not Started';
            opp.CloseDate = system.today();

            insert opp;

            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
            req.setObjectId(opp.Id);

            Approval.ProcessResult resu = Approval.process(req);

            // Verify the result
            System.assert(resu.isSuccess());

            System.assertEquals('Pending', resu.getInstanceStatus(),'Instance Status'+resu.getInstanceStatus());
            system.debug('status for approval::'+resu.getInstanceStatus());
            List<Id> newWorkItemIds = resu.getNewWorkitemIds();
            system.debug('newWorkItemIds ::'+newWorkItemIds );

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 =  new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
            req2.setComments('Approving request.');
            req2.setAction('Approve');
            req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});//UserInfo.getUserId()
            system.debug('req2::'+req2);
            // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
            req2.setWorkitemId(newWorkItemIds.get(0));
            system.debug('req3::'+req2);
            // Submit the request for approval
            Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req2);

            // Verify the results
            System.assert(result2.isSuccess(), 'Result Status:'+result2.isSuccess());

            System.assertEquals(  'Approved', result2.getInstanceStatus(),'Instance Status'+result2.getInstanceStatus());

            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
            T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass rp = new T_ApprovalUnderConditionClass(sc);
            rp.appRej('Approve');
            rp.approveAll();
            rp.ApproveUnderCon();
            rp.getProsInsts();
            rp.rejectAll(); 

       } 

    }
}
```

======

Comment: The above code works fine if I give ModifyAll permission to opportunity object  i

Comment: But I don't have to give Modify all to profile. Could any one please help.

Comment: I'm not sure on that one.  Is it necessary to run the entire test as the user with that profile?  Or could you create the Opportunity and Submit is as that user, and then revert back to yourself for the rest of the test?  Doesn't Apex usually run in system mode - in which case you're artificially restraining the permissions that the approval process would run under in reality?

Comment: No, its not necessary to run entire test as the user with that profile, only to create and submit opportunity I used. for remaining I wanted to return back, but How? Could you please give more hint. I tried But variable scope limits to that method only.

Comment: I think the normal rules apply here.  As long as you have declared the objects like opp and req, before the Runas block, then you'll be able to use them in the block and after you return to system mode.  I don't think its like shell in this regard (where su-ing to a different user completely reinitialises the context)